# How to close the "Profile" dialog box after logging into Google account in Chrome using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, capybara

I'm using Capybara and Selenium to automate the Chrome browser to perform a task which requires me to login to a Google account. Starting with version 100 of the Chrome browser, logging into a Google account causes a modal dialog regarding my Chrome Profile to display. How can I get that to close (or not appear in the first place)? (Using Ruby on Rails, Capybara, Capybara-Selenium, and Selenium-WebDriver)

Comment: Is it a system modal or just a modal dialog built into the web page? What does the dialog contain?

Comment: Well, I can't see it with the DevTools, and it is anchored to the top of the client area, but the page underneath and the browser overall can operate just fine with the dialog present, so I think it's some sort of modeless dialog, . My first thought was to find the HTML for the OK button but since DevTools doesn't seem to see it I'm assuming it's not in the window's DOM.

Comment: I know that Selenium has very limited support for modal dialog boxes (such as those from alert()), but I don't see anything that would deal with this dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't interact with system modals other than the `accept`/`alert` types - the only way to remove that would be to find out what Chrome command line switch will disable that behavior and configure your driver to pass that switch to Chrome. I don't know what switch that would be though.